# complex sed command syntax

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I have this *.sql file:

```
...some random text here ',0,'here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
...some random text here ',1,'here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
...some random text here ',2,'here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
...some random text here ',3,'here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
...some random text here ',4,'here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
[...]
...some random text here ',n,'here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
```

I need to sed this file adding a new part of path at the beginning of the path where the ID is > 0

Expected result:

```
...some random text here ',0,'here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
...some random text here ',1,'newpart/here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
...some random text here ',2,'newpart/here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
...some random text here ',3,'newpart/here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
...some random text here ',4,'newpart/here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
[...]
...some random text here ',n,'newpart/here/there/is/always/this/path',here some other random text...
```

It is possible with sed command or is too much complex? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

EDIT: If you downvote my question without telling me what I did wrong you will achieve nothing and I will never learn anything to be better the next time.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but you might want to look at the guidance for how to make your question a [mcve].

Comment: It's a sed syntax on a provided case with example and expected result, I don't really know what else is needed to understand the question.

Anyway thanks, I will read that again!

Comment: Your sample data is pretty messy to look at, I'm thinking a minimal example would be much simpler and then it would also be a lot easier to see what exactly changed between the input and the desired output. At the same time, you have obscured the structure to the point where we need to guess some things about the actual data. Does the vast bulk of placeholder text replace real data which could contain single quotes, commas, or other features we might otherwise use as good boundaries? What exactly is an `*.sql` file, anyway?

Comment: @tripleee — a`*.sql` file is another way of designating a `.sql` file.  It’s a plain text file containing SQL where the file name ends with `.sql`.  It’s common enough in database circles that I’m surprised you found it necessary to comment on it. The data isn’t bad; I’ve seen many questions with worse sample data.

Comment: I'm only speculating as to why somebody might have downvoted; the bulky sample data is distracting especially in the mobile view. I would expect `.sql` to be used for files containing actual SQL, but this looks roughly like CSV (though I imagine with your backgrund that the format *could* contain free-form SQL which might introduce exactly the sort of challenges which this apparently regular example data doesn't suggest or reveal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the random text won't ever match `,0,'here/there/is/always/this/path',` then it is doable:

```
sed "s%\\(,[1-9][0-9]*,'\\)\\(here/there/is/always/this/path',\\)%\\1newpart/\\2%" …
```

The single quotes in the data mean it is (probably) better to use double quotes around the regex, but that means you have to double-up the backslashes.  Ugh!  I'd prefer to put the command into a file (`script.sed`):

```
s%\(,[1-9][0-9]*,'\)\(here/there/is/always/this/path',\)%\1newpart/\2%
```

and run:

```
sed -f script.sed …
```

<sup>*Lightly tested code — it doesn't translate the line with `',n,'` because that isn't a number.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If there are no commas before the numeric field, perhaps

```
awk -F, '$2 > 0 { $3 = "\047newpart/" substr($3, 2) } 1' file
```

The condition checks that the second field is bigger than zero and the action says to insert `'newpart/` before the third field and then insert back the substring of the previous value after the starting single quote. (Inside single quotes, we can't insert a literal single quote verbatim, because that would terminate the quoted string; fortunately, Awk allows us to use an octal escape for the same character instead.) The final `1` says to unconditionally print every line.